# google Apps script API method "projects.updateContent" is giving error

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I have create script bound project by using apps script api but when i am updating the content using "projects.updateContent" it is giving error "Internal error encountered."

I am passing all the 3 files in the request, server_js,html and manifest json.

PUT https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/0AN5mKt2JLNFkUk9PVA/content?fields=files%2CscriptId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "name": "get Phrase",
   "type": "SERVER_JS",
   "source": ".gs file content"
  },
  {
   "name": "sidebar",
   "type": "HTML",
   "source":html file content
  },
  {
   "type": "JSON",
   "name": "appsscript",
   "source": "{\n  \"timeZone\": \"Asia/Kolkata\",\n  \"dependencies\": {\n  },\n  \"exceptionLogging\": \"STACKDRIVER\"\n}"
  }
 ]
}
```

i copied manifesto from already created standalone script project

Comment: I think that your request body is correct. But when I saw your endpoint, I thought that ``0AN5mKt2JLNFkUk9PVA`` of ``https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/0AN5mKt2JLNFkUk9PVA/content`` might be the folder ID of root folder. How about replacing it to the file ID of the standalone script? If you had intendedly replaced it for the question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the response,According to google's documentation That should be the drive id of the container bound script project for which i am updating the content(apps script files)